# Does an object emitting smoke also behave as an effector?

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire, mantaflow

I'm making a campfire in Blender 2.93 and I'm wondering if I need to make duplicates of the objects and set them to effectors. If my emitters are set to flow, then I can't set them to effector. So if they are set to flow, is the smoke not colliding with them? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: So I do indeed need to create duplicates and set those to effectors?

Comment: Well, that was what you asked in the question... what do you expect me to answer this time when you ask the same again?  ;)

Comment: Because in the title I asked if the flow objects also worked as effectors, but in the body, I asked if I need to make duplicates. I just need a little clarification. Thanks :)

Comment: You need a copy of the object to be the effector :)

Comment: Thank you so much :D